# replacing d3.js diagram instead of creating a new one every time

Tags: d3.js

I`m using d3.js combined with GWT and every time the javascript code for creating a pie chart is called it appends a new one rather than replacing the old one with new values.

How can I change this code so that the old one is removed before appending the new one?

```
var svg = d3.select(".body").append("svg")
            .attr("width", width)
            .attr("height", height)
          .append("g")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");
```

Answer (score 5):

Rather then changing your code i would suggest creating it once, then build your diagram using your data and taking a look at the .enter() and .exit() methods of d3.js - so if your data changes the library would add/remove some elements.

Answer (score 4):

Just add

```
d3.select(".body").selectAll("svg").remove();
```

before your code to remove all SVG elements.